# logrotate with custom log locations - do package managers overwrite the contents of /etc/logrotate.d/

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, logrotate

I'm using logrotate and I can see that things i've installed through the package manager install things in here:

> /etc/logrotate.d/

For instance I have the file `nginx` which contains this

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 14
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 0640 www-data adm
        sharedscripts
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi \
        endscript
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
        endscript
}
```

I've changed the location of the log files so this isn't going to be rotating them, since it's only looking in `/var/log/nginx/*.log`

Should I:

1) Simply edit this file to change the location it's looking in
2) Create a new conf file with my new log location and change the settings to however I would like them?

My concern is that the package manager may make changes to this file as I upgrade, so it may overwrite my changes?

I can't find any documentation anywhere which says whether it is safe to use and edit these files or whether package managers will overwrite your changes.

Can anyone offer any insight?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, package managers, such as yum/dnf/apt-get will never overwrite configuration files until you pass certain options.

Anyway it is valid concern, and you can give custom name, something like nginx.config